# Trying to parse JSON but got "Cannot create and populate list type"?

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

Recently I decided to write a Yahoo Weather PCL library for parsing those APIs (see here for the whole project: https://github.com/huming2207/YahooWeather.NET).

For the coding environment, I'm using Xamarin 6.0.1 with Mono 4.4.1 on Mac OSX 10.11.5, and Visual Studio update 3 on Windows 10 10586.

I've done most of the works and it works, except one thing.

The Yahoo Weather API query result should be something like this:

```
"item": {
 "title": "Conditions for Nome, AK, US at 02:00 PM AKDT",
 "lat": "64.499474",
 "long": "-165.405792",
 "link": "http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/Country__Country/*https://weather.yahoo.com/country/state/city-2460286/",
 "pubDate": "Sat, 09 Jul 2016 02:00 PM AKDT",
 "condition": {
  "code": "26",
  "date": "Sat, 09 Jul 2016 02:00 PM AKDT",
  "temp": "55",
  "text": "Cloudy"
 },
 "forecast": [
  {
   "code": "28",
   "date": "09 Jul 2016",
   "day": "Sat",
   "high": "55",
   "low": "50",
   "text": "Mostly Cloudy"
  },
  {
   "code": "39",
   "date": "10 Jul 2016",
   "day": "Sun",
   "high": "56",
   "low": "47",
   "text": "Scattered Showers"
  },
  {
   "code": "30",
   "date": "11 Jul 2016",
   "day": "Mon",
   "high": "53",
   "low": "48",
   "text": "Partly Cloudy"
  },
  {
   "code": "32",
   "date": "12 Jul 2016",
   "day": "Tue",
   "high": "59",
   "low": "47",
   "text": "Sunny"
  },
  {
   "code": "30",
   "date": "13 Jul 2016",
   "day": "Wed",
   "high": "58",
   "low": "50",
   "text": "Partly Cloudy"
  },
  {
   "code": "28",
   "date": "14 Jul 2016",
   "day": "Thu",
   "high": "53",
   "low": "51",
   "text": "Mostly Cloudy"
  },
  {
   "code": "30",
   "date": "15 Jul 2016",
   "day": "Fri",
   "high": "56",
   "low": "51",
   "text": "Partly Cloudy"
  },
  {
   "code": "26",
   "date": "16 Jul 2016",
   "day": "Sat",
   "high": "53",
   "low": "52",
   "text": "Cloudy"
  },
  {
   "code": "30",
   "date": "17 Jul 2016",
   "day": "Sun",
   "high": "62",
   "low": "52",
   "text": "Partly Cloudy"
  },
  {
   "code": "30",
   "date": "18 Jul 2016",
   "day": "Mon",
   "high": "56",
   "low": "47",
   "text": "Partly Cloudy"
  }
 ],
 "description": "<![CDATA[<img src=\"http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/26.gif\"/>\n<BR />\n<b>Current Conditions:</b>\n<BR />Cloudy\n<BR />\n<BR />\n<b>Forecast:</b>\n<BR /> Sat - Mostly Cloudy. High: 55Low: 50\n<BR /> Sun - Scattered Showers. High: 56Low: 47\n<BR /> Mon - Partly Cloudy. High: 53Low: 48\n<BR /> Tue - Sunny. High: 59Low: 47\n<BR /> Wed - Partly Cloudy. High: 58Low: 50\n<BR />\n<BR />\n<a href=\"http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/Country__Country/*https://weather.yahoo.com/country/state/city-2460286/\">Full Forecast at Yahoo! Weather</a>\n<BR />\n<BR />\n(provided by <a href=\"http://www.weather.com\" >The Weather Channel</a>)\n<BR />\n]]>",
 "guid": {
  "isPermaLink": "false"
 }
}
```

So I wrote a "Forecast" and a "Item" JsonObject class to declare for Json.NET library to parse the Json content, which looks like this:

Here is the "Item" class:

```
namespace YahooWeatherParser
{
    [JsonObject()]
    public class Item
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "lat")]
        public double Latitude { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "lon")]
        public double Longitude { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "link")]
        public string Link { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "pubDate")]
        public string PublishDate { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "condition")]
        public Condition Condition { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "forecast")]
        public Forecast Forecast { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "guid")]
        public Guid Guid { get; set; }
    }
}
```

...and here is the "Forecast" class:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace YahooWeatherParser
{
    [JsonArray]
    public class Forecast
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "code")]
        public int Code { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "date")]
        public string Date { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "day")]
        public string Day { get; set;}

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "high")]
        public int High { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "low")]
        public int Low { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "text")]
        public string Text { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Then I ran my code, I've got an exception like this:

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot create and populate list type YahooWeatherParser.Forecast. Path 'query.results.channel.item.forecast', line 1, position 1282.

So I Googled around for solutions. I tried if I replace these content below **(in "Item" class)**:

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "forecast")]
public Forecast Forecast { get; set; }
```

to:

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "forecast")]
public List<Forecast> Forecast { get; set; }
```

It returned me another different exception:

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. --->
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the
>   current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type
>   'YahooWeatherParser.Forecast' because the type requires a JSON array
>   (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly. To fix this error either
>   change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the
>   deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a
>   primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or
>   List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object.
>   JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to
>   deserialize from a JSON object. Path
>   'query.results.channel.item.forecast[0].code', line 1, position 1290.

So...what should I do next to deal with this problem? Great thanks for your help!

Regards,
Jackson.

Comment: Did you try "public Forecast[] Forecast { get; set; }" ?

Comment: Yes, I've got the same result as List<Forecast>

Comment: I'm using DataContractJsonSerializer and works like a charm, without any problem. Using Forecast[]

Comment: @x... Thanks. Now it works fine!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I try it using a clean project and actual newtonsoft json from nuget, your problem is in this line :

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace YahooWeatherParser
{
    [JsonObject]               // <= not [JsonArray] !!! 
    public class Forecast
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "code")]
        public int Code { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "date")]
        public string Date { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "day")]
        public string Day { get; set;}

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "high")]
        public int High { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "low")]
        public int Low { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "text")]
        public string Text { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: I had the same error "Cannot Populate and parse list type" when trying to deserialize a class with a custom IEnumerable implementation. Adding the [JsonObject] property worked, I believe it indicates to Json.Net not to consider this object as a regular list and let us handle serialization as a any object.

Answer (score 0):

With the second error, it sounds like you're creating a JObject somewhere in the code, but not casting it to a JArray, which is necessary because .NET doesn't understand the Newtonsoft JSON type. You can either get a JArray and use that, extract the JObject and convert it then, or use the .NET framework's own Serialization class.

```
foreach(JObject forecast in yourJObjectQueryResult["forecast"])
{
    string theForecast = forecast.ToString(Formatting.None); 
}

for (int i=0; i < (JArray)yourJObjectQueryResult["forecast"].Count; i++)
{

}
```

Comment: Okay thanks for your reply. I'm a bit confusing that, I might have declared the "Forecast" as a JArray. Do you mean I need to add a JsonConverter do convert it first, then do something else?

Comment: @JacksonMingHu Wherever you are getting that error in your code, breakpoint and check the the type for the object that has your JSON. Wherever you create the JObject at, you can just iterate over it and assign the values to an instance of your class. It isn't necessary to convert it to a JArray, I included the second loop just as an example.